# Is there a way to change the name of a function

Tags: javascript

I'm using a pattern from :
[Giulio Canti's blog](https://gcanti.github.io/2014/09/25/six-reasons-to-define-constructors-with-only-one-argument.html) so that I can create lots of constructors. I wish there was a way of setting the function name.  That is, given the constructor

```
function struct(cls, props) {
  function Struct(obj) {
    // add properties
    for (var name in props) {
      if (props.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        // here you could implement type checking exploiting props[name]
        this[name] = obj[name];
      }
    }
  }
  // the following doesn't work for me!
  // Struct.name = cls;
  return Struct;
}
```

When I use it to create an instance, e.g.

```
  var Person = struct('Person', {
  name: String,
  surname: String
});

var person = new Person({surname: 'Canti', name: 'Giulio'});
```

In the console I get the following:

[image: Chrome Console]

But I would prefer:

```
Person {name: "Giulio", surname: "Canti"}
```

Any suggestions on how I could accomplish that?

Comment: The name you're referring to here is the constructor of the object; of course you can change that, but is that really what you want? It's not just about names, it's about proper semantics.

Comment: As you can see, creating functions with dynamic names gets really ugly really fast http://marcosc.com/2012/03/dynamic-function-names-in-javascript/

Comment: What language are you coming from and what are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: There is no "anonymous function" here. All the functions are declared and have names. *person* is an object.